# Need a hand R, it appears an unexpected symbol

Tags: r

Im studying for an exam I have on monday and I don't understand why R doesn't accept this command :( can somebody help me?

```
c(sum(World$births[1:15] / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])
+ sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30]))
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>       "c(sum(World$births[1:15] / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])
>       sum"

Comment: Looks like you just didn't type the `+` sign in between the two lines. Its adding the first line to the second line to get the result. Your error has a space where the plus sign should be. Add the plus sign. Did you fail to copy-paste correctly? It works if you add the plus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a **fully reproducible example**

```
set.seed(123)
World = data.frame(births=runif(30))
totalpyWorld = runif(30)
```

I can duplicate your error with:

```
> c(sum(World$births[1:15] / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])
+ sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30]))
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"c(sum(World$births[1:15] / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])
sum"
```

Where **I've not typed the + on the second line** because the first line is waiting for a closing parenthesis. Now where this closing parenthesis belongs is a guess because **you've not told us what this is supposed to do**. It could either be:

```
> c(sum(World$births[1:15]) / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15]) + sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30]))
[1] 2.61555
```

Or:

```
> c(sum(World$births[1:15] / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])+ sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30])))
[1] 21.82067
```

Or maybe even, given that **the `c()` call is pointless if you are expecting a single value**, you are really expecting two values, there's a parenthesis **and a comma** missing and you want to really do this:

```
> c(sum(World$births[1:15]) / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15]),  sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30]))
[1] 1.243756 1.371794
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss a parenthesis at the first sum
I would have comment but I can't. not enough reputation

Comment: No. Its a real plus sign, not a continuation character. The closing parenthesis is the last one on line two.

Comment: I know ^^ but you miss to close the first sum

Comment: c(sum(World$births[1:15]) / sum(totalpyWorld[1:15])
+ sum(World$births[16:30]) / sum(totalpyWorld[16:30]))

Answer (score 0):

It is due to syntactically incorrect. In your case please check the missing ")"